# Invoke-Command from elevated powershell with non-elevated creds

Tags: permissions, powershell, administrator, runas

I'm trying to run a script that requires elevation to set certain registry values to allow CredSSP on local and remote computers and, during this script, I need to access a network share as a non-elevated account.

My initial thought was to try

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($networkShare) } -Credential $cred` where $cred is a non-elevated users' credentials. Unfortunately, that doesn't work due to [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/676872/invoke-command-parameter-bug-parameter-set-cannot-be-resolved).

The workaround given is to use `-ComputerName localhost` but that requires that my local machine be set up for PS Remote, which I don't want to do.

The best workaround I've found is to use

```
$foo = Start-Job -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($networkShare) }
$out = Receive-Job $foo
```

That works but it's just so ugly...can anyone help me find a better solution?

Comment: It's a scripting language. Sometimes ugly is the only option. What exactly do you find ugly about the solution that you have?

Comment: Well, I've come to realize that Receive-Job doesn't actually work so hot as I can't get access to the results from AccessNetworkShare()

Comment: What exactly is AccessNetworkShare()?

Comment: A listing of the files on a network share. The non-elevated user has rights to the share but the Local admin that runs an elevated command prompt doesn't

Comment: So it is the name of an array? I'm just confused because that isn't valid powershell syntax.

Comment: Sorry, it's edited now.